# Tags on user page showing anomalies in tag list

Tags: feature-request, top-users

My user account on Server Fault:

[image]

States that I'm kickass at answering questions with [security](/questions/tagged/security) and [security-policy](/questions/tagged/security-policy). But I'm not really; [I just got lucky with one particular answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants/293254#293254).

I have no idea how these tags are calculated (probably average score for each answer, giving me a massive score for those two tags. I'm fairly sure my total score from [windows-server-2008](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008) would be higher).

Is there some way that this can ignore outliers?

Comment: Same thing with my top tag on Physics: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:7433+[light] Now there are other posts, but this was ot the case a while ago--I had one +20 post and maybe a small post, that was it.